# Can I create an array of values in one column, based on array overlaps in another column?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two datasets that I'm trying to consolidate to represent all of the unique touch points for a given user.  I've gotten as far as using ARRAY_AGG to aggregate everything down to a single session identifier, but now I want to consolidate the identifiers themselves and am stuck.

The source data looks like this:

> | Session_GUID | User_GUID | Interaction_GUID |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Session_1 | User_1 | Interact_A |
> | Session_1 | User_1 | Interact_B |
> | Session_1 | User_2 | Interact_C |
> | Session_2 | User_2 | Interact_D |
> | Session_3 | User_3 | Interact_C |
> | Session_4 | User_4 | Interact_E |

And I've aggregated it down with a simple

```
SELECT 
  Session, 
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT User_GUID), 
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT Interaction_GUID) 
FROM 
  source_table
GROUP BY 
  Session
```

Which gets me here:

> | Session | User_GUID_Array | Interaction_GUID_Array |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Session_1 | [ User_1, User_2 ] | [ Interact_A, Interact_B, Interact_C ] |
> | Session_2 | [ User_2 ] | [ Interact_D ] |
> | Session_3 | [ User_3 ] | [ Interact_C ] |
> | Session_4 | [ User_4 ] | [ Interact_E ] |

Now I'd like to aggregate *everything* based on matches in **either** of the two arrays.

So from the above, Session_1 and Session_2 get grouped together based on User_GUID matches, and Session_3 gets added too based on Interaction_GUID matches.

This seems like it should be do-able based on some sort of "do another ARRAY_AGG if these intersect/overlap conditions are met" logic.  But I'm at the limits of my SQL knowledge and haven't been able to figure it out.

The end result I'm looking for is this:

| Session_Array | User_GUID_Array | Interaction_GUID_Array |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [ Sessionion_1, Session_2, Session_3 ] | [ User_1, User_2, User_3 ] | [ Interact_A, Interact_B, Interact_C, Interact_D ] |
| [ Session_4 ] | [ User_4 ] | [ Interact_E ] |

Comment: Looks like you want an algorithm for finding [graph components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping by more than one column usually requires a recursive CTE, but in this case the grouping is by array intersection. One way to accomplish this is with a user defined table function that maintains two two-dimensional arrays, one for each column. As a row goes through, the function checks to see if it's seen the values before (in either of the two two-dimensional arrays). If it has seen at least one value in one of the groups, it returns the group number. A CTE can then use those group numbers for the array_union aggregation.

This approach will only work for small partitions. In this example the partition is "1", which means the entire table. If the table is large, the UDTF will run out of memory. This approach requires a partition such as a date, ID of some sort, etc. that keeps the partitions small (a few thousand rows perhaps). If the partitions are significantly larger than that, this approach won't work.

```
create or replace function GROUP_ANY(ARR1 array, ARR2 array)
returns table(GROUP_NUMBER float)
language javascript
as
$$
{
    initialize: function (argumentInfo, context) {
        this.isInitialized = false;
        this.groupNumber = 0;
        this.arr1 = [1];
        this.arr2 = [1];
    },
    processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
        var arraysIntersect;
        var g;
        if(!this.isInitialized) {
            this.isInitialized = true;
            this.arr1[0] = row.ARR1;
            this.arr2[0] = row.ARR2;
        } else {
            arraysIntersect = false;
            for (g=0; g<=this.groupNumber; g++) {
                if(arraysOverlap(this.arr1[g], row.ARR1) || arraysOverlap(this.arr2[g], row.ARR2)) {
                    this.arr1[g] = this.arr1[g].concat(row.ARR1);
                    this.arr2[g] = this.arr2[g].concat(row.ARR2);
                    arraysIntersect = true;
                }
                if (arraysIntersect) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!arraysIntersect){
                this.arr1.push(row.ARR1);
                this.arr2.push(row.ARR2);
                this.groupNumber++;
            }
        }
        if (arraysIntersect) {
            rowWriter.writeRow({GROUP_NUMBER:g});
        } else {
            rowWriter.writeRow({GROUP_NUMBER:this.groupNumber});
        }
        function arraysOverlap(arr1, arr2) {
            return arr1.some(r=> arr2.includes(r));
        }
    },
    finalize: function (rowWriter, context) {/*...*/},
}
$$;

create or replace table T1(Session_GUID string, User_GUID string, Interaction_GUID string);

insert into T1 (Session_GUID, User_GUID, Interaction_GUID) values
('Session_1',   'User_1',   'Interact_A'),
('Session_1',   'User_1',   'Interact_B'),
('Session_1',   'User_2',   'Interact_C'),
('Session_2',   'User_2',   'Interact_D'),
('Session_3',   'User_3',   'Interact_C'),
('Session_4',   'User_4',   'Interact_E'),
('Session_5',   'User_5',   'Interact_F'),
('Session_6',   'User_4',   'Interact_G'),
('Session_7',   'User_6',   'Interact_E'),
('Session_8',   'User_8',   'Interact_H')
;


with SESSIONS as
(
select   Session_GUID
        ,array_unique_agg(User_GUID) USER_GUID
        ,array_unique_agg(Interaction_GUID) INTERACTION_GUID
from     T1
group by Session_GUID
), GROUPS as
(
    select * from SESSIONS, table(group_any(USER_GUID, INTERACTION_GUID) 
         over (partition by 1 order by SESSION_GUID ))
)
select   array_agg(SESSION_GUID) SESSION_GUIDS
        ,array_union_agg(USER_GUID) USER_GUIDS
        ,array_union_agg(INTERACTION_GUID) INTERACTION_GUIDS
from     GROUPS
group by GROUP_NUMBER
;
```

Output:

| SESSION_GUIDS | USER_GUIDS | INTERACTION_GUIDS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [ "Session_5" ] | [ "User_5" ] | [ "Interact_F" ] |
| [ "Session_1", "Session_2", "Session_3" ] | [ "User_1", "User_2", "User_3" ] | [ "Interact_A", "Interact_B", "Interact_C", "Interact_D" ] |
| [ "Session_8" ] | [ "User_8" ] | [ "Interact_H" ] |
| [ "Session_4", "Session_6", "Session_7" ] | [ "User_4", "User_6" ] | [ "Interact_E", "Interact_G" ] |

Comment: Thanks so much, this is a great help.  I did have one question about this bit at the end of the UDF:

`function arraysOverlap(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.some(r=> arr2.includes(r));`

I think I'm following the rest of the code, but don't quite understand this.  Apologies, I've no experience with javascript.